# update table based on JSONB columns joins

Tags: postgresql, sql-update, jsonb

I'm trying to update my table and the code that isn't working is

```
UPDATE A
   SET person_id = B.id 
  FROM B
 WHERE A.info.EmpNumber = B.info.EmpNumber
```

both the info columns are of type jsonb

`A.info` looks like this

```json
{
  "position": "Data Engineer",
  "EmpNumber": "382159"
}
```

`B.info` looks like this

```json
{
  "salary": 80000,
  "EmpNumber": "382159"
}
```

Could you point me in the right direction?

The error is

> ```
> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table A
> LINE 4: WHERE
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use `->>` operator in order to extract the value from the related key such as

```
UPDATE A
   SET person_id = B.id 
  FROM B
 WHERE A.info->> 'EmpNumber' = B.info->> 'EmpNumber'
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Je8Z3Dg-)</kbd>